# delete everything but the pattern and the next line vim

Tags: regex, vim

Trying to figure out how to delete everything except a pattern from vim using the regex capabilities.

Specifically, I'm trying to delete everything but the "United States" line as well as the line immediately following it (from the Arch Linux Mirrorlist).
So this...

```
## Austria
Server = http://mirror.easyname.at/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
## United States
Server = http://mirror.cs.pitt.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
## Thailand
Server = http://mirror2.totbb.net/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
```

Should transform into this... (and continue this for every instance of the United States line)

```
## United States
Server = http://mirror.cs.pitt.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
```

The line I've attempted to use to complete this is:

```
:v/## United States\n\_.\{-}\_$/d
```

If I understand correctly, :v selects everything but the pattern. The pattern I'm trying to feed it is the United States line plus the next line (\n) and everything after that to the end of the line (\_.\{-}\_$) and then delete all this junk (/d).

However, when executing that line I get only the lines with the United States. Something like this:

```
## United States
## United States
## United States
...
```

What should I do to save the line after the United States line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, :v selects everything but the pattern. The pattern I'm trying to feed it is the United States line plus the next line (\n) and everything after that to the end of the line (\_.\{-}\_$) and then delete all this junk (/d).

*Close*. But not quite. There's a subtle distinction. `:v` (or `:g!`) will run a particular command *on every line* that does not match the regex. Which is really really close to what you want, just not quite there. Here's the problem. The line:

```
## United States
```

*does* match your regex, this is true. Therefore, this line does not get deleted. However, the line right after this then gets tested, and

```
Server = http://mirror.cs.pitt.edu/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
```

Does not match your regex. So it does get deleted.

The easiest solution I can think of is to match every location line (So your lines starting with `## <location`>) *other* than `## United States`, and then for each of those matches, delete that line and the following. For example:

```
:g/## \(United States\)\@!/,+1d
```

Comment: Just nitpicking but I would use `,+1d_` io `normal dj`. It can make a big difference on large files due to the black hole register being used. Equivalent to `normal "_dj`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Oh, that's a great suggestion. I actually originally tried to delete both lines from `ex` mode, but I had a brain-fart and tried `2d` (which is not "delete two lines" but "delete line two") and forgot that ranges exist.

Answer (score 0):

Also can be used this regex:

```
:%s/## United States\n^.*\n\zs\|.*\n//g
```